# Need to figure out this upvote/downvote edge case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this upvote/downvote problem and I keep running into 3 problems.

Code:

```
$(function() {

$('button').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        $container = $(this).parent(),
        $buttons = $container.children('button'),
        $count = $container.children('.count'),
        was = $container.data('was');

    // 0 case
    if ($this.is('.up')) {
        if (was === 0 || $this.is('.active')) {
            vote = 0;
        } else {
            vote = 1;
        }
    } else {
        vote = -1;
    }

    if ( was + vote < 0 ) {
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    }

    if( $this.hasClass('active') ){
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        $count.text( was );
    } else {
        if( $buttons.filter('.active').length ){
            $buttons.toggleClass('active');
        } else {
            $this.toggleClass('active');
        }
        $count.text( was + vote );
    }

});

});
```

Live Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TV7G4/3/) ​

I've labeled each case in the demo (6 cases total)

Problems:

- Case #1: If there is an active class on it and it originally was (data-was) 0, then clicking down should add an active class to down turning it red and keeping the count at 0.
- Case #2: If the active class is on the down button and the original score was (data-was) at 1, then the active class should go on up, and the count should go to 3.
- Case #3: If there is an up class on the button and the original score was (data-was) 1, then clicking down should make it go to 0 and put an active class on down, clicking up should make it go to 0 removing the active class from up, and clicking up with an active class on down should take it to back to 1.

Cases #4 - #6 all behave normally, so if its not clear what the problems are, they should all behave like that, but ***never*** go below 0.

This keeps getting kind of complex, so I'm debating just showing the actual returned score from the ajax request, but I don't want any latency between clicks, so that's why I'm approaching it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo that simplifies the logic to essentially 2 steps. First step is make an adjustment if the other button is active, then make adjustment for the current button.

The most important change is forgetting what "was" and only working with what "is" and storing any changes. I think you will see that storing the current value, and working with that makes the code a lot easier to read and debug.

Also instead of trying to assign an actual value to your current `vote` variable, will notice that I simply use add/subtract which makes it a lot easier when you run into many logic branches ( lot's of `if`). This also allows some separation of conditions within the code... such as doing the reset first if needed, then dealing with the current button.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/TV7G4/6/

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        $container = $(this).parent(),
        $count = $container.find('.count'),
        curr_votes = $container.data('vote_count'),
        is_upVote = $this.hasClass('up'),
        this_active = $this.hasClass('active'),
        $otherButton = $this.siblings('.vote'),
        vote_change = 0;


    /* reset vote_count if other already active*/
    if ($otherButton.is('.active')) {
        $otherButton.removeClass('active');
        is_upVote ? vote_change++ : vote_change--;

    }

    /* adjust vote_count for this action */
    if (this_active) {
        is_upVote ? vote_change-- : vote_change++;
    } else {
        is_upVote ? vote_change++ : vote_change--;
    }


    /* always toggle class on curent button*/
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    /* update vote count */
    curr_votes += vote_change;
    curr_votes = curr_votes < 0 ? 0 : curr_votes;

    $count.text(curr_votes);
    /* store the current value*/
    $container.data('vote_count', curr_votes);



});
```

Comment: Hmm it's still a little off. On case 1, it could be 0 if the original score has say 20 downvotes and 0 upvotes (score is still negative until it gets above the 0 threshold). On case 3, if I click up, and then down and up again, it takes me to 2, instead of 1.

Comment: It seems there are criteria within your voting that haven't been made clear in the scope of question. Other than toggle values the rest is not clear. Can't help without a full breakdown of voting criteria

Answer (score 0):

Here is you [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/TV7G4/7/).  I have functionality as I would think you wold want.  I didn't utilize the `data` attribute